# Finding integer values in a string and replace them after processing

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have a long string with integer values. I want to find the integer values with Regex.Replace and replace them after multiplying with a variable.

Something like the following

`string text = "The the quick brown fox 23jumps o65ver th66e lazy dog.";`

will be

`The the quick brown fox VAL*23jumps oVAL*65ver thVAL*66e lazy dog.`

I used the `Regex.Replace(text, @"(\d+)", @"$1");`. However, this cannot process the $1 and replace the found integer.

Comment: `\d` will match only 1 digit. You need `\d+`

Comment: @RuiJarimba sorry that was \d+

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew VAL here is an integer value and I would like to use it after evaluating.

Comment: @PoulBak That form does not evaluate the VAL*$1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a match evaluator:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"\d+", m => $"{VAL * int.Parse(m.Value)}")
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/CiOoUr):

```
var text = "The the quick brown fox 23jumps o65ver th66e lazy dog.";
var VAL = 4;
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, @"\d+", m => $"{VAL * int.Parse(m.Value)}"));
// => The the quick brown fox 92jumps o260ver th264e lazy dog.
```